# Normal distribution question. Is it 4.603 or 4?

Tags: normal-distribution

The diameter of washers produced by a machine has a mean of 0.502mm and a standard deviation of 0.005mm. Suppose that the maximum tolerance allows for diameters between 0.496mm and 0.508mm inclusive, otherwise a washer is classified as defective. Determine the percentage of defective washers produced by the machine, assuming that the diameters are normally distributed, and hence state how many defective washers you expect to see in a sample of 20 washers produced by this machine.

0,496 < x < 0,502

P[0,496- 0,502 /0,005 < x-m/sigma < 0,508 - 0,502 / 0,005]

P[-1.2 < z < 1.2]

1.2 = 0,3849

2x 0,3849 = 0,7698= 76,98%

100- 76,98= 23,02%

20 x 23,02 /100= 4,603 defective washers in my sample of 20

Remarks: Should the final answer be stated as 4.603 or 4? The question doesn't specify

Comment: I'd say 4.603. In the absence of precision indicators you should give your answer to 3 dp.

Comment: You need use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor The post is readable, not every user knows $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @szw1710 Not knowing is  not a excuse, especially on a site about learning. MathJax is one of the aspects of this site that keeps it so pristine (compare to, e.g., *Yahoo! Answers*).

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor In general I agree with your opinion. But some compromise is also needed. My best regards.